# [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for ... found on class in Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know why I'm having this warning:

> W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for `lh`.
>   found on class com.example.model.Liturgia

### Code for getting data:

```
    DocumentReference calRef = db.collection(CALENDAR_PATH).document(fechaYY).collection(fechaMM).document(fechaDD);
    calRef.addSnapshotListener((calSnapshot, e) -> {
        if ((calSnapshot != null) && calSnapshot.exists()) {
            mLiturgia = calSnapshot.toObject(Liturgia.class);
            DocumentReference dataRef = calSnapshot.getDocumentReference("lh.1");
            // ...
```

### Model

```
public class Liturgia {
    private Breviario lh;
    //...

    public Liturgia() {
    }

    @Exclude
    public void getlh() {
    }

    @PropertyName("lh")
    public void setLh(Breviario lh) {
        this.lh = lh;
    }
}
```

### Documents

**(A): `calRef`**.

As you can see in the code, first I read this document:

[image]

**(B): `calSnapshot`**.

And then, in the second instance, I read another document that is referred in one field of type `document` in **(A)**:

[image]

And I map this second document to the `Liturgia.class`.

If I try to name the method as `set lh()` or I try without `@PropertyName("lh")` the warning shows always.

The code works as expected, but I don't want to see this warning.

I see this answer: [W/Firestore: [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for class Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58025961/5587982) but in my case, the name of the property and the name of the method are the same.

Comment: Hey A.! Please edit your question and add a screenshot of a document.

Comment: @AlexMamo I edited the question.

Comment: I see I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the following warning:

> W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [CustomClassMapper]: No setter/field for lh found on class com.example.model.Liturgia

Because the `lh` property in your `Liturgia` class is of type `Breviario`, while in the database is an array of Strings. Both must match. So if you need to keep the current database data, change that property to be of type `List<String>`.

Besides that, using:

```
@PropertyName("lh")
```

It is useless because the property in the database is already called `lh`. So there is no need for that.

**Edit:**

Here are the steps for solving the entire problem:

1. Declare `lh` property to be of type `HashMap<String, Object>`
2. Remove the @Ignore annotation
3. Change the return type of the getter void to return the `HashMap<String, Object>`
4. Set a `HashMap<String, Object>` into the setter.

So, here si the getter:

```
public HashMap<String, Object> getLh() {
    return lh;
}
```

And for the setter:

```
public void setLh(HashMap<String, Object> lh) {
    this.lh = lh;
}
```

Comment: The `lh` property in the database is of type array and **not** String! So you need change it to a `Lis<String>`. There is no use for adding `@Exclude` in front of the setters.

Comment: Should, be good now. Good luck with your project and show us when you go live with it.